# Как сгруппировать элементы ListView? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, gridview

Вопрос простой. Мне нужно сгруппировать мой `ListView` (в котором `GridView`) где-то так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что я перелопатил кучу статей и везде используется куча кода в `Code-Behind` (даже коллекцию часто задают в конструкторе). Мне нужно нормальное `MVVM` решение.

Comment: [ListView grouping](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)?

Comment: @tym32167 я как раз об этом. там все в Code-Behind прописано

Comment: Никто не мешает CollectionViewSource объявить в VM и настраивать группировки и сортировки из VM. Или опишите более подробно что вы хотите получить и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @АлексейЛосев как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Что нужно было сделать, так это добавить в ресурсы `CollectionViewSource` и в него добавить `GroupDescription`. В моем случае это:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="envVariables" Source="{Binding Variables}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Hive"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

А в `ListView` установить `ItemsSource` следующим образом:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource envVariables}}">
```

и добавить `GroupStyle`:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```